# CSS Responsive gallery break after few rows

Tags: html, css, responsive, image-gallery

I am trying to build a responsive gallery from this [tutorial](https://timnwells.medium.com/create-a-simple-responsive-image-gallery-with-html-and-css-fcb973f595ea). And here is my attempt on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-morse-dqcd9?file=/index.html)

Whatever I try there is one little problem. It looks nice but somewhere in half or after half only four columns are shown instead of 5 as shown in the image below:

[image]

Code
CSS (media query not included)

```
#gallery {
  line-height: 0;
  -webkit-column-count: 5; /* split it into 5 columns */
  -webkit-column-gap: 5px; /* give it a 5px gap between columns */
  -moz-column-count: 5;
  -moz-column-gap: 5px;
  column-count: 5;
  column-gap: 5px;
}

#gallery img {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  margin-bottom: 5px; /* to match column gap */
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="gallery">
  
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">       <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">
  
  </div>
 
 </body>
```

Thanks for any help.

//EDIT
This looks like best gallery i found - https://codepen.io/maxvoltar/pen/eYOPdMG

Comment: @Paulie_D Thats why i wrote code too and is even shortest i did not included media query

Comment: @Paulie_D because there is no point in putting links to images inside because it can get invalid and then there will be no value for future SO users with the same problem. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Anyway its updated with links and help is still welcome :)

Comment: Interesting problem. Made me test this instead of watching TV :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't exactly know why the grid is failing you in this specific scenario, but I did solve the problem by changing up your HTML and CSS to be a little more specific.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Responsive Image Gallery" />
    <meta name="author" content="Tim Wells" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/styles.css" />
    <style type="text/css"></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="gallery">
      <div class="combo">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
        />
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="combo">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
        />
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="combo">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
        />
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="combo">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
        />
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="combo">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
        />
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="combo">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
        />
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="combo">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
        />
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="combo">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
        />
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="combo">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
        />
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="combo">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
        />
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="combo">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
        />
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="combo">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
        />
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="combo">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
        />
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="combo">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
        />
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="combo">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
        />
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#gallery {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#gallery img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.combo {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 2px;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 760px) {
  .combo {
    width: 33%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .combo {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```

In general, I would not use grid for containers you want to flood-fill with an indeterminate number of items.

Grid is best for containers that have a set number of special items that you want to move around responsively.

Also, unless there is a specific reason to do otherwise, I think it is necessary to put an upper-bound on your container width.

Here is the sandbox revised with flex-box and the width upper bound.

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-noyce-stpo9?file=/src/styles.css

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial depends on the number of images and the image dimensions. Columns fill up vertically. The tutorial uses exactly 24 (small and big) images.

With two more images, it works in your case as you can see below. Run the code, click on full screen, and use a big screen resolution to see 5 columns.

```css
#gallery {
  line-height: 0;
  -webkit-column-count: 5; /* split it into 5 columns */
  -webkit-column-gap: 5px; /* give it a 5px gap between columns */
  -moz-column-count: 5;
  -moz-column-gap: 5px;
  column-count: 5;
  column-gap: 5px;
}

#gallery img {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  margin-bottom: 5px; /* to match column gap */
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #gallery {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #gallery {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Responsive Image Gallery" />
    <meta name="author" content="Tim Wells" />

    <style type="text/css"></style>
  </head>
  

  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Responsive Image Gallery" />
    <meta name="author" content="Tim Wells" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/styles.css" />
    <style type="text/css"></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="gallery">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      /><img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
      />
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
      />
      <img
      src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
    /><img
      src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
    />
    <img
      src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620920709484-995504fbecd2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80"
    /><img
      src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620827252031-146d52644aac?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80"
    />

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Maybe a good workaround is to use flexbox, which might require a different HTML layout as well.